# Correct approach of rendering page depending on Javascript data

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am using google app engine to create a test app.

I have a handler that renders the initial webpage, which includes a button. When I click the button, I want to send some information back, so I use a request like the following:

```
var request = { "myData": {
        "key1": value,
        "key2": value
        } };
$.ajax({
    url: '/my_handler',
    type: 'GET',
    data: JSON.stringify(request),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc  
});
```

and then I get the data in `myHandler` like that:

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logging.info(self.request)
```

Now I want a different page to be rendered based on that data.
However, if I try to call `self.response.write("something")` inside `MyHandler` it (logically) doesn't render it in the webpage, but returns it in `successFunc(response)`.

How can I give control back to python to render my templates?

It just feels kind of weird to control how my webpage looks both from Python and Javascript.
Is my approach completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typically two ways to control how a page is rendered :

1. The old, traditional, server-side way is to associate a URL with each view and have the server compute the HTML before sending it to the browser. That's where Python can help. In this case any change to the HTML requires to change or refresh the page.
2. The client-side way, which is to use static HTML and JS files, and then send AJAX request to the server to get info or to perform computations that cannot be done on the client. In this case, the Python code only provides the answers to the AJAX requests (usually in JSON), and then Javascript decides what to do with that answer, like add a button, remove an image etc.

Of course, both methods can be used at the same time, for example using the Python code to pre-render the pages and then some javascript+AJAX to make the page more dynamic.

In your case you have those two choices :

- Keep the logic on the server, in Python. This means that you must abandon AJAX and rather redirect the user to a new page for which Python will be able to generate the right HTML code. You can do this in javascript with this code :

  `window.location.href = "/mypage?myparams=myvalues";`
- Keep AJAX because you want the user to stay in the current page. In that case, check out how a javascript framework such as jQuery helps you manipulate the page to update whatever your want. As an intermediate step, you could generate some partial html in Python (like a `<div>`), return it in the AJAX response, and have jQuery insert it in the page. [Here is a documentation on how you can use jQuery to update the page](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/traversing-manipulating).

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. So, it is not "frowned upon" to start with rendering a template with python and then using javascript to manipulate it?

Comment: In your case I do not think you need any javascript. A simple HTML form with key1 and key2 and the button will do to post the data resulting in a new page. Example here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates

Comment: @voscausa Yes, you are right, I used a simplified example here. The actual use is something like getting geolocation through javascript and passing that data back.

Comment: It is not frowned upon, but it's a bit strange in terms of separation of concerns : for a given zone if your page, the HTML will be generated by both python and JavaScript code, which can make development harder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Python to render a new page, why use ajax. If you post data without ajax, you do not have to handle the ajax response and you receive the new page.

But if you want to use ajax to send the data, you can get the new rendered page after handling the ajax response in the browser. A kind of redirect. The `<url_to_get>`, can be part of the ajax respons:

Update your succesFunc using:

```
top.location.href="<url_to_get>";
```

or

```
window.location.href = "<url_to_get>";
```

Ajax makes sense if you want to update the state of you page.

Comment: Thanks, I will try without using ajax too. I am very new to web development and I saw everyone using ajax and to tell you the truth I didn't even consider doing the request in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

To get a JSON payload from the app to the browser reliably, you need to set the content type. Try adding

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
```

before you do the `write`.

Comment: Thank you. So when I call self.response.write, do I need to pass JSON data? Ideally, I would like to do something like `template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('page_to_render_based_on_js_data.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())` in my handler. Is that possible?

Comment: I assumed from your question that you wanted to pass JSON data, so if you set the Content-Type to application/json, then yes, pass a serialized JSON object to `write`. You can construct JSON data from a template, but that's an unnecessarily hard way of doing things. But if you want to do that, I suggest naming your template with a `.json` extension, just to making things easier on yourself.